# Poynting vector for a whole spectrum

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations, poynting-vector

Considering an electric and magnetic plane wave, $E(t)=E_p(\omega)e^{i\omega t}$ and $H(t)=H_p(\omega)e^{i\omega t}$, where $E_p(\omega)$ and $H_p(\omega)$ represent the frequency dependent peak amplitudes of the wave. The time-averaged Poynting vector is defined as $<S_x> = \frac{1}{2}\text{Re}\{E_p(\omega)H_p^*(\omega)\}$ with unit $\left[\frac{V}{m}\frac{A}{m} = \frac{W}{m^2}\right]$ (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector#Time-averaged_Poynting_vector).

How to determine the total power if there is a whole radiation spectrum? For example, if you want to know the power carried by the solar spectrum? I would expect something like

$$ S_{tot} = \frac{1}{2} \text{Re}\{ \int\limits_0^\infty E_p(\omega) H_p^*(\omega) d\omega \} \,.$$

However, this expression has a wrong unit $\left[\frac{V}{m}\frac{A}{m}\frac{1}{s} = \frac{W}{m^2}\frac{1}{s}\right]$...

My question: what is the correct expression of the **total power** in function of the **reciprocal** electric and magnetic field?

Comment: What is $E_p(f)$? It looks like it might be the Fourier transform of the time-domain E-field, in which case it won't have units of $\text{V/m}$. Same for $H_p(f)$. If you saw these equations and definitions somewhere, consider mentioning where and linking the source if applicable.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I made some edits in the post, I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Confusion is caused by misleading notation. $E_p (\omega), H_p (\omega)$ is the first and the second case, are slightly different things.

In the case of monochromatic wave - they are the whole electric and magnetic field.
Because there is a wave with only one frequency I would drop the $\omega$ index, and denote them as $E, H$.

And in the second case - it is a density of electric(magnetic) field for a given frequency.

To see the connection between the first and the second case you may write:
$$
E = \int E_p (\omega) d \omega^{'} = \int E \ \delta (\omega - \omega^{'}) d \omega^{'}
$$
So the units of $E_p (\omega)$ are $\left[\frac{V s}{m}  \right]$. Now perform the integration ($T \rightarrow \infty$):
$$
S = \frac{1}{2T} \text{Re} \left[\int_{-T}^{T} dt \int d \omega \int d \omega^{'} E_p (\omega) H_p^{*} (\omega^{'}) e^{i (\omega - \omega^{'}) t  / T} \right] = 
\frac{1}{2} \text{Re} \left[ \int d \omega  \ E_p (\omega) H_p^{*} (\omega) \right]
 $$
Checking the dimensions of S:
$$
S = \left[\frac{V s}{m} \frac{A s}{m} \frac{1}{s} \frac{1}{s} \frac{s}{s}\right] = \left[\frac{W}{m^2} \right] 
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have three questions: 1. Why does the electric field depend on $\omega$ and the magnetic field on $\omega '$? 2. I guess T is the time, and you take the time integral to average over time? 3. How do you end up in the last form of the expression, without the exponent and only an integral over $\omega$ and not $\omega '$?

Comment: @Frederic 1) By $E_p (\omega)$ one means, that there is not just a monochromatic wave, but a wave packet, compising waves with different frequencies, like the daylight is not a single red or green wave, but a complicated mixture 2) $T$ is a time, over which the averaging is computed. During the period, the magintude of $S$ changes, but the average can be computed. Here it is tacitly assumed, that $T$ is largen than the period of any wave in the packet.

Comment: @Frederic 3) I've substituted the expansions of form $\int E_p (\omega) d \omega$ (same for $H_p (\omega)$), and I've denoted it with the prime index $\omega^{'}$ in order to distinguish from the omega. Then I've performed integration over time $\int_{-T}^{T} dt e^{i (\omega - \omega^{'}) t} = \delta (\omega - \omega^{'})$ and eliminated by delta function $\omega^{'}$. Here I am inaccurate , but the general idea works as follows.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the comments! I now have one new question: To calculate the Poynting vector, you still need to divide the expression on the right by the infinite time T? This is not possible? Or is there a trick to make it work? $S=\frac{1}{2T}\text{Re}[...]$ with T=infinity

Comment: @Frederic here I've been inaccurate, the division by the infinite time cancels. The correct formula is $\frac{1}{T} \int_{-T}^{T} e^{i \omega t / T} dt = 2 \pi \delta (\omega)$, so the integration over $t$ will give a factor of $T$, which will cancel with the $T$ in the denominator. I'll edit the answer

Comment: @Frederic useful reference - http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e102/lectures/ExponentialDelta.pdf

Comment: Thank you for answering all my questions, I already learned a lot! :) But I still have some questions: 1. Now, the exponential is $e^{i(\omega-\omega')t/T}$, where did this $1/T$ in the exponent come from? 2. I am again confused because if we look to the final expression, then we do not have the unit of the Poynting vector anymore $\left[ \frac{1}{s}\frac{Vs}{m} \frac{As}{m}=\frac{W}{m^2}s\right]$...

Comment: @Frederic integration over $\omega, \omega^{'}$ still remains, thus the factor $[\frac{1}{s^2}]$ and $s / s$ from the $dt$ and $1/T$ cancel each other. With the finite time interval, frequencies are restricted to lie in range $[-\pi/T, \pi /T]$ - so $1/T$ is some normalization in the exponent $e^{i \omega t  / T}$, which scales the $\omega$ to $[-\pi, \pi]$

Comment: Okay, I think we are almost there. Only the first part with the units I do not understand. In the last version of the expression we have $d\omega$, $E(\omega)$ and $H(\omega)$ with corresponding units $[1/s]$, $[Vs/m]$ and $[As/m]$. If these units are multiplied, the result is $\left[ \frac{W}{m^2} s \right]$. I do not see how you cancel this "$s$" away?

Comment: @Frederic,  After the above redifiniton  $\omega$ is dimensionless, because it is normalized by $T$. $E_p (\omega), H_p (\omega)$ now have dimensions the same, as the integrated field : $\left[V / m \right], \left[A / m \right]$. So we have finally $\left[\frac{s}{s} \frac{V}{m} \frac{A}{m} \right]$

Comment: Okay, mathematically I think I understand it. However, physically, this sounds still strange to me. If I have the electric and magnetic field in frequency space (with unit [Vs/m] and [As/m]) and I want to calculate the Poynting vector according to your final equation, then I will naively end up with a result in unit [W/m s]. How to determine the Poynting vector when you have given the Fourier transformations of the electric and magnetic field. Do you have to transform/convolute them first, or..?